# Extracting Country Names and Years

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using VB.NET and trying to extract Years and Countries from Random sentences; IF BOTH ARE AVAILABLE:
My input will be something like the one below:

```
This is just the title and has no year or country:
Preamble with only year 1999 and no country:
I was born in 1990 in Canada, I was born to love, and be loved.
She was born in 2000 in Malaysia and she likes fishing.
My mother was born in South Africa and she love all her sons and daughters, she was born in 1960.
My Dad was born in a small village in France in 1955. He loves my Mom.
and finally thanks from USA, without a year.
```

I want to get the following output from the above:

```
***EMPTY
***EMPTY
1990 - Canada
2000 - Malaysia
1960 - South Africa
1955 - France
***EMPTY
```

I was reading this whole morning about `REGEX`, I think it might do the trick;
but I gave up;
Can anyone help;
THANKS IN ADVANCE...

Comment: You'll probably need an entire list of countries since regexp has no idea what a "country" is. You can get the years pretty reliably with `\d{4}` but you'll run into trouble with a sentence like `"In 1999, our family moved to 1234 Main St in New York City, USA".` There's nothing _regular_ about these sentences, so using _regular_ expressions to extract information from them will be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks macek for the quick response; this is what I've figured too, but assuming I have the list of all countries, how to use it?

Comment: Well, crude as it may be, you could loop through an entire array of countries and scan the paragraph for matches of each country. You'll have additional trouble if you use things `"United States"`, `"USA"`, `"United States of America"`, and `"U.S.A."` as you will have to check for each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you can build a list of countries, you would assemble it in a series of alternations like so:

```
(Canada|Malaysia|France|South Africa)
```

The long list must be optimized, but that's another story (see below).

Then you can use a regex like this:

```
^(?=.*(\b\d{4}\b))(?=.*\b(Canada|Malaysia|France|South Africa)\b)
```

To capture the year and country to Group 1 and 2. In the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/11), see the captures in the **right-hand pane**.

**Captures:**

```
1990    Canada
2000    Malaysia
1960    South Africa
1955    France
```

**Optimizing the List of Countries**

First, you will need to organize the list such that if a country name is a substring of another—for instance the two Guinea and Guinea-Bissau, Sudan and South Sudan, Dominica and the Dominican Republic—the longest comes first so that it has a chance to match.

You also need to know your input. For instance, do you need to take into account variations such as *the U.S.*  and *the United States of America*?

Also, you would want to `Fairyland` and `Fantasyland` as `Fa(?:ir|ntas)yland`, which helps the engine match (or fail) faster. With a list of 256 countries, creating such an optimized list is a challenge, but some tools can help you with that. `regex-opt` and `Regex::Assemble` come to mind.

Comment: @hector Thanks, glad you like it. :)

Comment: FYI, added `Optimizing the List of Countries` section at the bottom. :)

Comment: This became great reference.